# Salesforce record id within an org ever recycled / reused

Tags: salesforce-id

Will a record id within an org ever be recycled / reused.  For example, Event with id A is created, then deleted, emptied from recycle bin, years later a new Event is created in the same org, could it have an id of A?

Comment: That's a good question...   Out of curiousity, what's your use case.

Comment: Hi Nivyaj:  We're exporting the data out of salesforce into a data warehouse.  If an object is deleted in salesforce, but not in the data warehouse, and then an id is reused in salesforce, it'd break things.

Comment: Thanks. That's something that I oughta keep in mind when doing our ETL.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/salesforce-id-uniqueness) and the following comment from Josh Birk (Salesforce.com Technical Evangelist).

> I think that's correct on the second question. I would see that an ID would be recycled at some point, but the chances of seeing it again in the same org are pretty remote.

Comment: To elaborate: I've heard from many people in R&D that in the current implementation IDs are always unique (outside of sandboxes) - but there's no guarantee the implementation won't change in the future.